# how to store key securely

Tags: authentication, key-management

I will receive some secret key from server which I will use as an authentication key for a MAC function in the future. But my question is how do I store this key securely on my machine?
Will I have to re encrypt it with some other key and store it like that?

Comment: Unless you go for fancy measures like a HSM key extraction is likely on machine compromise. Even with a HSM it's probably possible to induce it to compute valid MACs.

Answer (score 1):

A good idea is to encrypt the key and then store on your system. Using a good  encryption algorithm like AES with a strong key is advisable.[TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) is one such tool which can help you in saving your key securely.

Comment: The problem is that this shifts the problem to keeping the TrueCrypt key safe. For hot data that isn't much of a gain. For cold data it might work.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Yes exactly where do I store the TrueCrypt key then safely?

Comment: As Cory J mentioned, at some point you need to store the trusted information in your head.

Comment: You can use a keyfile along with a password. It will be a hassle when the key is used frequently, but ensures security.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to utilize something like [steghide](http://steghide.sourceforge.net/) to hide your key in an image or audio file.

Maybe combine this with the TrueCrypt suggestion. Put your key in a TrueCrypt volume, steghide the TrueCrypt keyfile and remember the passphrase in your head.